# Cannot solve 'This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.'

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, wrapper

I'm using:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
```

and wrapper:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

But still on all syncs IntelliJ IDEA gives me:
[image]

I've once found a workaround, using an **old** gradle version and older build tools it was working. But this cannot be "true", anyone else facing such issues?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 does not support Android gradle Plugin 4.1 version yet. You have two options: either downgrade AGP and use IDEA: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2`

or switch to Android Studio 4.1+

Android Plugin 4.1 will be available in IDEA starting from the very first EAP of 2021.1. version EAP should start this week.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great, I'm using some special config with a multiplatform library (kotlin) and that wasn't supported by prior Android Studio so i migrated to IntelliJ IDEA. Great to be back at Android Studio. Thanks! Everything working, building and syncing!
Unfortunately didn't find that answer searching the web myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In 2022 this error still comes up from time to time.
I had the exact same error for opening one of my old Android projects in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition) and faced the exact same error.

But it was solved by writing this line to "dependencies" section of project-level "build.gradle" file

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

*You just need to change the version in this line so the error gets resolved*

Answer (score 0):

Just update top-level build gradle in dependencies block with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`